# c code to find differences using tar

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix, operating-system

I need to write a C program for finding the differences between two folders, folder1 and folder2.tar and update the contents of folder2.tar with folder1. So I have written using tar --diff utility command like below:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
system("tar df folder2.tar folder1 > file.patch");
system("tar uf folder2 folder1"); //Assume folder2 is the extracted version of folder2.tar
}
```

Here I have few questions:

1. Firstly, I am not able to get the differences in contents of folders into the separate file. I am getting only the modified filename in the folder and time modified
2. Secondly, as will be many files in the folders, and after modifying a random file in folder1, how do we specify the path to update only that specific file in folder2.tar?
3. How do we write the code for the above scenario?

Any idea !!!!! Please help me if you have so !
Thanks

Comment: is this homework ? please tag it as homework if it is the case

Comment: You so need to use version control instead of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
tar xf folder2.tar
diff -rq folder1 folder2
```

You can then get the modified filenames from the output of diff and pass them to `tar -u`. Feel free to wrap it in system() so you can call it a C program, but I'd advise you to make it a bash script: Smaller, faster and you don't need to recompile when you make changes.

Comment: Thanks alexis.....now i could see the differences in the content. But how do i update this particular file which has been modified in folder1 with the same file in folder2.tar? How do I specify the path to it? It knows that particular file in the folder has been modified only after it runs the command

Comment: I don't understand your question. The output of diff gives you the pathname. Capture it and use it. `man tar` will tell you how to tell tar to update a particural pathname.